# Python Conditinal operator

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

Can you please explain how the below python code is evaluated to be True

```
if 50 == 10 or 30:
   print('True')
else:
   print('False')
```

Output: True

Comment: `(50 == 10) or 30` is how Python parses it.  `30` is "truthy", so the statement evaluates as True. What it looks like you intended was `50 in (10, 30)` or `50 == 10 or 50 == 30`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thank you
Is there any better way to write `if x== a or x==b` where a similar comparison takes place over multiple variables?

Comment: `if x in (a, b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
if 50 == 10 or 50 == 30:
   print('True')
else:
   print('False')

#output: False
```

Otherwise, the way you had written the code, it would first evaluate 50==30 and determine that it is false.  Then it would move to 30 without any comparison operators.  Since 30 is a non-zero integer, it has boolean value of True.  It therefore returns True for the entire or statement.

Comment: In such a case I would probably prefer `50 in (10, 30)`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yes, of course.  I am just trying to make the left_to_right evaluation of the truth value more clear for OP.

Answer (score 1):

When you use or it is separating 2 statements and if one of them is returning true the whole statement will return true because it is "OR" between them and 30 as a value is returning true. if you are not convinced try running this code.

```py
if 30:
   print(True)
```

Answer (score 1):

All non-zero positive values in Python return True. Therefore, the if statement evaluates to True and prints out accordingly.